# Issue Deploying TypeScript Application to Vercel: "Cannot find module" Error

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my TypeScript application to Vercel. The application deploys without any issues locally, but I keep encountering an error during the build stages when attempting to deploy online.

Here's the error message I'm encountering:

```
2 | Failed to compile.
./layout.tsx:5:27
Type error: Cannot find module './components/analytics' or its corresponding type declarations.
  3 | import LocalFont from "@next/font/local";
  4 | import { Metadata } from "next";
> 5 | import { Analytics } from "./components/analytics";
    |                           ^
  6 | 
  7 | export const metadata: Metadata = {
  8 |   title: {
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
Error: Command "pnpm run build" exited with 1
```

I have confirming that the files are in their correct directories and that everything is in order. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem before, or does anyone have insights into how to resolve it?

My code is written in TypeScript, so I initially thought about adding a `.tsx` extension to the end of the folder directory I'm trying to access. However, this approach led to another error: "an import path can only end with a '.tsx' extension when 'allowImportingTsExtensions' is enabled.ts(5097)."

I've attempted various solutions, including reinstalling TypeScript and even commenting out the problematic import to see if the application would deploy without it. Surprisingly, even with the import commented out, the same issue persists. It's noteworthy that the error message consistently points to the exact location, even when the code in question is commented out.

Comment: It's very hard to read text without any punctuation

Comment: try reading it again, i've edited it

Comment: ChatGPT can be very helpful sometimes